# postgresql, connection limit for different roles

Tags: postgresql, connections, limits

Is possible setup in `postgresql.conf` connection limit for specified role globally (in some `.conf` file) or individually?

For example, I have 3 roles and `max_connections = 600`.

1. Need to setup max 10 connections globally for all 3 roles.
2. Need to setup max 10 connections for 1st role, 20 connections for 2nd role, and 30 connections for 3rd role.

About second point, I read somewhere it is possible, but not via config file?

Thank you.

Comment: `alter role set connection limit ...`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you. So directly in some conf file it is not possible, as I thought? For example some `connection_limit_role` parameter. Thanks.